# Copy folder & files with labeled files but strip the label?

Tags: finder, folder-action

Is there an easier way to copy a folder that contains files with (colored) labels applied and strip those labels than making an Automator droplet/application?

So perfect would be having this to happen, but have it happen "by default" if I press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>...

[image]

Automator goes like this...

```
Application receives files and folders as input
Duplicate Finder Items
Get Folder Contents (actually, the "Repeat for each subfolder found" should be checked)
Label Finder items (nothing selected, with is what happens when you click "x")
```

Seems clunky, but when I've got Smart Folders returning, eg, all yellow labeled files, I don't want copies when I back a folder up by duplicating it.  The app works fine, but wanted to know if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Automator application as a service instead, and then apply a keyboard shortcut against that service as follows:

In **System Preferences**, go to **Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services**

Find the service on the list.

To the right of the service name, double-click.

Enter the desired shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Hrm, that's asking for my password, then copying without removing the label.  Seems promising, though.